PutHDFS Processor Failed to write in HDP2.5.0 HDFS
I am using Apache Nifi 1.28, i have configured the apache nifi in Windows system, My HDP2.5.0 is running on the VM, I want to ingest data from my local file system to HDFS service running in Hortonworks HDP2.5.0. I have done the following tasks:

Exported the core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml and placed in my apache nifi conf folder.
I have provided the necessary configuration in puthdfs processor in apache nifi canvas. like hadoop configuration resources the local path of core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml files.

I want to acquire that do i still need to provide additional hadoop jar files to put in lib folder of apache nifi? The following files i have included in the lib folder but still i am unable to write a single byte in the hdfs. Below is the image of all hadoop client libraries jar files

i am also attaching the core-site.xml file as well, do i need any specific configuration in hdfs-site.xml as well, i have tried many configuration but not able to write a single byte in hdfs. Please help
    
    <property>
      <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
      <value>hdfs://192.168.136.131:8020</value>
      <final>true</final>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>fs.trash.interval</name>
      <value>360</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>ha.failover-controller.active-standby-elector.zk.op.retries</name>
      <value>120</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.http.authentication.simple.anonymous.allowed</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.falcon.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.falcon.hosts</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hbase.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hbase.hosts</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hcat.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hcat.hosts</name>
      <value>sandbox.hortonworks.com</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hdfs.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hdfs.hosts</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hive.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hive.hosts</name>
      <value>sandbox.hortonworks.com</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hue.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hue.hosts</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.livy.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.livy.hosts</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.hosts</name>
      <value>sandbox.hortonworks.com</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.root.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.root.hosts</name>
      <value>sandbox.hortonworks.com</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.security.auth_to_local</name>
      <value>DEFAULT</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.security.authentication</name>
      <value>simple</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.security.authorization</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.security.key.provider.path</name>
      <value></value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>io.compression.codec.lzo.class</name>
      <value>com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>io.compression.codecs</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec,com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec,com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>io.file.buffer.size</name>
      <value>131072</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>io.serializations</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>ipc.client.connect.max.retries</name>
      <value>50</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>ipc.client.connection.maxidletime</name>
      <value>30000</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>ipc.client.idlethreshold</name>
      <value>8000</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>ipc.server.tcpnodelay</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.webinterface.trusted</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>net.topology.script.file.name</name>
      <value>/etc/hadoop/conf/topology_script.py</value>
    </property>
        <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.nifi.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.nifi.hosts</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    
  </configuration>```


Do not add any files to nifi's lib directory, please show the error you are encoutnering

Thank you @BryanBende for your prompt reply, let me remove all the additional jar fles in lib and reproduce the error and reconstruct the question.

Moreover, i have the AI , he tolde to download that compression lzo jar library, is there anything which i have to update in nifi.properties

Dear @BryanBende here below i have reproduced the error and reconstructed the question, here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79143566/apache-nifi-puthdfs-processor-issue-puthdfs-failed-to-write-to-hdfs-java-lang

i have added one more question dear @BryanBende, here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79144416/apache-nifi-puthdfs-processor-replicated-to-0-nodes-instead-of-minreplication

Please try using Nifi and HDFS in Docker, not raw Windows or VM , especially since there is no support for HDP and hasn't for 7+ years
