Apache Nifi: Puthdfs Processor -replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1). There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded
I am using Apache NIFI 1.28 version, i am trying to create a minimalistic data flow where i am generate the data and want to ingest in HDFS in `HDP (Hortonworks Data Platform) 2.5.0 , i am getting the following error,
2024-10-31 15:31:07,952 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1] o.apache.nifi.processors.hadoop.PutHDFS PutHDFS[id=d2b7ad77-0192-1000-e937-9d1797c4e0fd] Failed to write to HDFS
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: IOException thrown from PutHDFS[id=d2b7ad77-0192-1000-e937-9d1797c4e0fd]: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /pakistan/.db7bd26c-6ccc-4dcf-88f0-fc3965286fc3 could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1641)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getNewBlockTargets(FSNamesystem.java:3198)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3122)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:843)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:500)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:640)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2313)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2309)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2307)

    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.read(StandardProcessSession.java:2711)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.read(StandardProcessSession.java:2656)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.hadoop.PutHDFS$1.run(PutHDFS.java:405)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1930)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.hadoop.PutHDFS.onTrigger(PutHDFS.java:328)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1361)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:247)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.AbstractTimeBasedSchedulingAgent.lambda$doScheduleOnce$0(AbstractTimeBasedSchedulingAgent.java:59)
    at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: File /pakistan/.db7bd26c-6ccc-4dcf-88f0-fc3965286fc3 could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1641)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getNewBlockTargets(FSNamesystem.java:3198)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3122)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:843)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:500)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:640)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2313)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2309)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2307)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1584)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1529)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1426)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:139)
    at jdk.proxy7/jdk.proxy7.$Proxy171.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.lambda$addBlock$11(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:500)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.internal.ShadedProtobufHelper.ipc(ShadedProtobufHelper.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:500)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:437)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:162)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:366)
    at jdk.proxy7/jdk.proxy7.$Proxy172.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.addBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DataStreamer.java:2009)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1811)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:751)
2024-10-31 15:31:07,958 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1] o.a.n.c.s.StandardProcessScheduler Stopping PutHDFS[id=d2b7ad77-0192-1000-e937-9d1797c4e0fd]
2024-10-31 15:31:07,958 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1] o.a.n.controller.StandardProcessorNode Stopping processor: PutHDFS[id=d2b7ad77-0192-1000-e937-9d1797c4e0fd]
2024-10-31 15:31:07,959 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1] o.a.n.c.s.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent Stopped scheduling PutHDFS[id=d2b7ad77-0192-1000-e937-9d1797c4e0fd] to run
2024-10-31 15:31:07,960 WARN [org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Statistics$StatisticsDataReferenceCleaner] org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem Cleaner thread interrupted, will stop
java.lang.InterruptedException: null

below is the image of processor group with error on the canvas

here below is the puthdfs processor configuration image.

Also i am attaching the core-site.xml
  <configuration>
    
    <property>
      <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
      <value>hdfs://192.168.136.131:8020</value>
      <final>true</final>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>fs.trash.interval</name>
      <value>360</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>ha.failover-controller.active-standby-elector.zk.op.retries</name>
      <value>120</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.http.authentication.simple.anonymous.allowed</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.falcon.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.falcon.hosts</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hbase.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hbase.hosts</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hcat.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hcat.hosts</name>
      <value>sandbox.hortonworks.com</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hdfs.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hdfs.hosts</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hive.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hive.hosts</name>
      <value>sandbox.hortonworks.com</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hue.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hue.hosts</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.livy.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.livy.hosts</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.hosts</name>
      <value>sandbox.hortonworks.com</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.root.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.root.hosts</name>
      <value>sandbox.hortonworks.com</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.security.auth_to_local</name>
      <value>DEFAULT</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.security.authentication</name>
      <value>simple</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.security.authorization</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.security.key.provider.path</name>
      <value></value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>io.compression.codec.lzo.class</name>
      <value>com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>io.file.buffer.size</name>
      <value>131072</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>io.serializations</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>ipc.client.connect.max.retries</name>
      <value>50</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>ipc.client.connection.maxidletime</name>
      <value>30000</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>ipc.client.idlethreshold</name>
      <value>8000</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>ipc.server.tcpnodelay</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.webinterface.trusted</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>net.topology.script.file.name</name>
      <value>/etc/hadoop/conf/topology_script.py</value>
    </property>
        <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.nifi.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.nifi.hosts</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>
    
  </configuration>

below is the hdfs-site.xml configurations:
  <configuration>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.block.access.token.enable</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.blockreport.initialDelay</name>
      <value>120</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.blocksize</name>
      <value>134217728</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.client.read.shortcircuit</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.client.read.shortcircuit.streams.cache.size</name>
      <value>4096</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.client.retry.policy.enabled</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.cluster.administrators</name>
      <value> hdfs</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.content-summary.limit</name>
      <value>5000</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.datanode.address</name>
      <value>192.168.136.131:50075</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.datanode.balance.bandwidthPerSec</name>
      <value>6250000</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
      <value>/hadoop/hdfs/data</value>
      <final>true</final>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir.perm</name>
      <value>750</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.datanode.du.reserved</name>
      <value>1073741824</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.datanode.failed.volumes.tolerated</name>
      <value>0</value>
      <final>true</final>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.datanode.http.address</name>
      <value>192.168.136.131:50075</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.datanode.https.address</name>
      <value>192.168.136.131:50075</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.datanode.ipc.address</name>
      <value>0.0.0.0:8010</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.datanode.max.transfer.threads</name>
      <value>16384</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.domain.socket.path</name>
      <value>/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/dn_socket</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.encrypt.data.transfer.cipher.suites</name>
      <value>AES/CTR/NoPadding</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.encryption.key.provider.uri</name>
      <value></value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.heartbeat.interval</name>
      <value>3</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.hosts.exclude</name>
      <value>/etc/hadoop/conf/dfs.exclude</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.http.policy</name>
      <value>HTTP_ONLY</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.https.port</name>
      <value>50070</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.journalnode.edits.dir</name>
      <value>/hadoop/hdfs/journalnode</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.journalnode.http-address</name>
      <value>0.0.0.0:8480</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.journalnode.https-address</name>
      <value>0.0.0.0:8481</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.accesstime.precision</name>
      <value>0</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.audit.log.async</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.avoid.read.stale.datanode</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.avoid.write.stale.datanode</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir</name>
      <value>/hadoop/hdfs/namesecondary</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.checkpoint.edits.dir</name>
      <value>${dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir}</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.checkpoint.period</name>
      <value>21600</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.checkpoint.txns</name>
      <value>1000000</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.fslock.fair</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.handler.count</name>
      <value>25</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.http-address</name>
      <value>192.168.136.131:50070</value>
      <final>true</final>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.https-address</name>
      <value>192.168.136.131:50470</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.inode.attributes.provider.class</name>
      <value>org.apache.ranger.authorization.hadoop.RangerHdfsAuthorizer</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
      <value>/hadoop/hdfs/namenode</value>
      <final>true</final>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir.restore</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address</name>
      <value>192.168.136.131:8020</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct</name>
      <value>1.000</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address</name>
      <value>192.168.136.131:50070</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.stale.datanode.interval</name>
      <value>30000</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.startup.delay.block.deletion.sec</name>
      <value>3600</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.write.stale.datanode.ratio</name>
      <value>1.0f</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.permissions.enabled</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.permissions.superusergroup</name>
      <value>hdfs</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.replication</name>
      <value>1</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.replication.max</name>
      <value>50</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.support.append</name>
      <value>true</value>
      <final>true</final>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
      <value>true</value>
      <final>true</final>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>fs.permissions.umask-mode</name>
      <value>022</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>nfs.exports.allowed.hosts</name>
      <value>* rw</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
      <name>nfs.file.dump.dir</name>
      <value>/tmp/.hdfs-nfs</value>
    </property>


    
  </configuration>

I shall be grateful if some one could resolve this error.

FWIW, HDP is long end-of-life. But forget nifi for a second. Are you able to use hadoop fs commands to do anything with HDFS?

yes i am able to run hadoop fs, i would like to mention here, when i start the puthdfs processor in nifi, it creates the directory  at namenode which i have mentioned in puthdfs configurations, but it does not transfer any byte into it, it seems that when it is replicating on datanodes it is unable to resoolve internal ip, my anticipation.

Have you tried hadoop fs copyFromLocal? Nifi would be using an equivalent API Method for that. Otherwise, there's hadoop namenode commands to check cluster health and exit safe mode, for example. Otherwise, you might have to reformat your namenode or use the datanode UI to check connectivity... The error isn't specific to Nifi

you might be right that, it is not specifi to nifi it might be due to old HDP2.5 version issue, thats why i have installed standalone the hadoop on windows 11 and then used the puthdfs processor  it successfully ingested the data and problem resolved. but does this argument is valid that hdfs at hdp2.5.0 has support issues or deprectaed.

Hadoop 2.7.x is still ran by large companies. HDP deprecation is unrelated to the error you're getting. My point was that I would not start a brand new environment using these versions, and I would use a Linux VM or Docker, not Windows.
